# NullPointerException when using indexEmbedded and containedIn of Hibernate Search

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I have 2 relating entities and getting NullPointerException when they are indexed.

The entities are

```
public final class Application implements java.io.Serializable {
    ....
    private java.util.Set roles; // NOT nullable
    ....
}

public final class Role implements java.io.Serializable {
    ....
    private ch.adnovum.nevisidm.service.dto.Application application;

    ....
}
```

The mapper classes are

```
public class ApplicationMapper extends AbstractMapper {
    ...
    @Override
    public void map(Class<?> clazz) {
        ...
        indexedMapping
        .property("roles", ElementType.FIELD)
        .containedIn();
    }
}

public class RoleMapper extends AbstractMapper {
    ...
    @Override
    public void map(Class<?> clazz) {
        indexedMapping
       .property("application", ElementType.METHOD)
       .indexEmbedded()
       .prefix("app.")
       .targetElement(Application.class);
    }
}
```

The exception is

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.updateContainedInMaxDepth(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:641)
at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.updateContainedInMaxDepths(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:602)
at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.checkForContainedIn(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:592)
at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.initializeMemberLevelAnnotations(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:461)
at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.initializeClass(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:383)
at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.<init>(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:151)
```

I use Hibernate Search 4.1.1 and lucene 3.5.
Does anybody have any idea what can go wrong?

Thanks,
V.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that what you're experiencing is a bug that has been solved in a later version of Hibernate Search.

You are using a very old version of Hibernate Search (published in 2012, out of date since January 2013). The latest version is 5.7.0.Final, released in February 2017.

It is possible that upgrading to the latest version of Hibernate Search will solve your problem; though there may be quite a lot of work involved to upgrade from such an old version.

If you can't put much effort into solving your issue, you could try to at least upgrade to the latest 4.x (4.5.3.Final, released in 2015) using the [migration guides](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateSearchMigrationGuide).

Comment: Hi Yoann, thanks for the reply! I tried to upgrade to 4.5.3 but I faced the same NullPointerException. Also I tried to upgrade to 5.6 but as you mentioned there were many compilation errors in the code as classes were missing, etc.